# Game engine C++ and objective C/Xcode coding

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-engine

I'm quite confused.

I want to develop a 3D game app. I have Unreal engine or Unity to choose from.
Both of them are coded in C++. 
Where I have to use objective c that is the main language for iOS?

Can I do the app totally in the game engine Unity/UDK, coded there and then send it to the app store without any programing in objective c and straight from the game engine without using Xcode?

I really hope that the 6 month of full immersion in objective C/xcode were a waist of time.

Sorry if this question is very low level

Thank you

Regards

CL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Unity3D, it is not C++ it is C#

Both are great engines, but if you are new to this, suggest going with Unity3D. Its easier to learn, with tons of free or cheap, easily accessible scripts and art.

and yes you can create the whole game in-Unity-engine, submit to apple and have it Live to the world (without knowing or needing any objective C)
You can also upload it to the app store submission with only a few setup steps.
You will need to download and install XCODE, but you don't need to learn any XCODE programming or project setup as unity does it all for you.

You won't need to learn OGL, or shader language (Unity comes with a suite of free, optimized mobile shaders) though it is fun to learn how to make your own later on.

Any native (objective C) stuff you might need, you can all do just by buying cheap plugins for unity that others have written. (usually in the $20 -$50) range.

You will need.. an apple developer account $100 a year.
Unity for iOS... basic or pro version.
a Mac, or a Hackintosh on a PC  (mac mini is the easiest / compromise price route to go)
an iOS device would also help. (suggest getting several different ones for testing, or asking friends)

You could also do Droid instead of iOS. You dont need a mac then. But iOS apps make most of the money. something like 70% iOS 30% droid.

have fun!

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking into programming for iOS... Yes you will need to know Objective-C (as it is the main language) and Xcode.

If you are looking to develop a 3D game, start looking into OpenGL ES.

You can't just write a game for Unreal/Unity and send it to the app store... doesn't exactly work that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I develop for Unreal and then integrated into Xcode what I have done in Unreal/Unity? Where I can find information about the integration process. I think is only the interface part I have to write in c++? I really appreciate your help. Open GL ES is not really what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create an Objective-C wrapper.

This is a good start point.

[TECH TALK: BRIDGING UNITY AND THE IOS SDK](http://millipede.com.au/blog/bridging-unity-and-the-ios-sdk/)

Comment: Thank you. I guess the same concept apply If I want to use Unreal instead of Unity. Is that correct? Thank you very much again.

Comment: I don't have experience with Unreal, but if it is a game engine as Unity, develop your game using it and then wrap them to run on iOS, Android, ...